# Scrapy not crawling all links recursively

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I need all internal links from all pages in the website for analysis. I have searched found lot of similar question. 
I found this code by [Mithu](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/175827/extracting-certain-products-from-a-webpage-using-scrapy) which gives closes possible answer. However this is not providing all possible links from the second level of depth of pages.
The generated [csv](https://github.com/subhankor/data/blob/master/data.csv) file has only 676 records however the website has 1000 records.

[image: 1000 records]
**Working Codes**

```
import csv // Done to avoid line gaps in the generated csv file
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from eylinks.items import LinkscrawlItem
outfile = open("data.csv", "w", newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
class ToscrapeSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "toscrapesp"
    start_urls = ["http://books.toscrape.com/"]

    rules = ([Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r".*"), callback='parse', follow=True)])


    def parse(self, response):
        extractor = LinkExtractor(allow_domains='toscrape.com')
        links = extractor.extract_links(response)
        for link in links:
            yield scrapy.Request(link.url, callback=self.collect_data)

    def collect_data(self, response):
        global writer                                  
        for item in response.css('.product_pod'):
            product = item.css('h3 a::text').extract_first()
            value = item.css('.price_color::text').extract_first()
            lnk = response.url
            stats = response.status
            print(lnk)
            yield {'Name': product, 'Price': value,"URL":lnk,"Status":stats}  
            writer.writerow([product,value,lnk,stats])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For extract links try this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
import csv 

outfile = open("data.csv", "w", newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
class BooksScrapySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'books'
    allowed_domains = ['books.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        books = response.xpath('//h3/a/@href').extract()
        for book in books:
            url = response.urljoin(book)
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_book)

        next_page_url = response.xpath(
            "//a[text()='next']/@href").extract_first()
        absolute_next_page = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
        yield Request(absolute_next_page)

    def parse_book(self, response):

        title = response.css("h1::text").extract_first()
        price = response.xpath(
            "//*[@class='price_color']/text()").extract_first()
        url = response.request.url

        yield {'title': title,
               'price': price,
               'url': url,
               'status': response.status}
        writer.writerow([title,price,url,response.status])
```

Comment: Your code works fantistically. Thank your for the guidance. However my ultimate objective is to get only URL, Title and status for website to track all invalid links, so ultimately next page link will not work with me :(. Will try to edit this code to suit my need. As far as I know for this my last two days full day research says I have to use from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor to achieve this. If you can help on that bit would be indebted to you.

Comment: Also any idea why would link extractor exclude some links ?